# wordpress paginate, link to the right page

Tags: posts, customization, pagination

I have posts that I paginate, instead of showing them on their single post page I would like to show them on the archive page. I've built my own archive-page with custom functions. I just added

**news-archive.php**

```
$news_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'paged' => $paged
);
$news = new WP_Query($news_args);
...
```

So I have another page where I show the latest news on, and a snippet of that news. When clicked on the news link I would like it to go to the correct page number on the archive.

How can I accomplish this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Conditionally, 5 news should link to the same page as you are showing of 5 posts per page on news-archive.php template ? And the "another page where U show the latest news on" should link to calculated archive page ?

Comment: @Shazzad That's correct!